# “The Great” vs. “The Magnificent”

Tags: names

There are many people in history whose names are appended with such phrases, for example Alexander the Great (Kingdom of Macedon) and Suleiman the Magnificent (Ottoman Empire). **My question is :** are they equivalent in their own language? If not completely so, what might be the difference?

For me, it’s somehow intriguing to find the subtle differences between the appendices to the names of the emperors, and I’d be grateful if any help is provided!

: )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English Language.

Comment: The example of "Æthelred the Unready" suggests that these epithets can run a wide range of meaning, and each should be considered individually.

Comment: @AndyT I’m sorry, this is the first time that I’ve asked a question in this community.

Comment: @user662852 Thanks, that’s helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they are the Great. But in case of Suleiman, he has a nickname magnificient when he lives. So we may use magnificient instead of great.